# Why does my custom buildtype gives apk not signed error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-build-type

I have the following `app.gradle` configuration:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    debug {
        debuggable true
        // more configs here
    }

    staging {
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-DDEBUG_FLAG"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `staging` build type gives error:

> The apk for your currently selected variant is not signed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, only buildtypes `release` and `debug` are configured with signing keys. For custom buildtypes, you have to manually set it by:

1) using the signing config of debug

```
staging {
    signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    ...
}
```

OR

2) inherit from a buildtype that has signing key configured

```
staging {
    initWith debug
    ...
}
```

OR

3) [generate a new key](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#generate-key) and create your own signing configuration

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        keyStagingApp {
            keyAlias 'stagingKey'
            keyPassword 'stagingKeyPassword'
            storeFile file('../stagingKey.jks')
            storePassword 'stagingKeyPassword'
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

then configure the staging like so:

```
staging {
    signingConfig signingConfigs.keyStagingApp
    ...
}
```

Comment: why you not just rename `staging` to `debug` ...while there are only two build-types?

Comment: i need staging buildtype. i just removed debug buildtype for brevity.

Comment: with this configuration being absent, this isn't one MCVE anymore; hence it is relevant to understand the actual situation - therefore my question about it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve